# Equation cant be referenced - split environment

Tags: equations, labels, split, autoref

i'm currently working on using the equation environment in combination with split. I later want to reference this equation with only one number, but it simply doesnt work

```
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{split}
    (\partial_\mu \partial^\mu + m^2) D_R(x-y) = -i \dfdist{x-y} \\
    D_R(x-y) = \qq{if $x^0 < y^0$}
\end{split} \right.\label{equ:scalar-source-cond}
\end{equation}
```

The `\left\{` is there to embrace both equations.

I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How are `\dfdist` and `\qq` defined?

Comment: Have you considered replacing `\left\{ \begin{split}` with `\begin{cases}` and `\end{split} \right.` with `\end{cases}`?

Answer (score 1):

The simple code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{split}
    (\partial_\mu \partial^\mu + m^2) D_R(x-y) = -i \dfdist{x-y} \\
    D_R(x-y) = \qq{if $x^0 < y^0$}
\end{split} \right.\label{equ:scalar-source-cond}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

produces ten errors when run, all marked on line 8, that is, at `\end{split}`.

Of course, the fact that the label is not set is completely irrelevant: after so many errors, the main thing to do is to fix them.

How is beyond the capabilities of my crystal ball that has no idea of what `\dfdist` and `\qq` mean.

Probably using `cases` is a better idea.

If I remove `\dfdist` and `\qq`, I get no error, but a self-explaining warning:

```
Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use `split' here;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned' on input line 8.
```

and the equation ***can*** be referenced. But `split` is definitely out of place there anyway.